# How can I view and manipulate directory contents that are hidden from root?

Tags: safari, macos, root

As root (!) I get this:

```
sh-3.2# pwd
/Users/madler/Library/Safari
sh-3.2# ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

I'm not sure how even root is prohibited from looking at or modifying this (and other) directories, but it is. Is there a way around it?

As for what I'm up to, I would like to figure out where open tabs and windows are stored by Safari, and restore them from a backup. Safari lost them all somehow. I am able to see and retrieve the contents of that directory in the backup, but I am not able to replace the contents of that directory either with the restore function of the backup or manually as root.

I am running Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can enable Full Disk Access for Terminal to get further access. Even further access to system files can be had by disabling SIP (System Integrity Protection) - although I would not recommend leaving it disabling in general.

You can enable Full Disk Access by opening System Preferences > Security & Privacy, and then under the "Privacy" tab select "Full Disk Access". After unlocking, drag Terminal.app into the list to give it full disk access.

SIP can be disabled by booting into Recovery Mode (reboot with Cmd+R held down), and then opening Terminal.app and running the following command:

```
csrutil disable
```

When you reboot, your Mac will start up with SIP disabled. You can run the same command again in Recovery Mode by replacing "disable" with "enable" in order to re-enable SIP after making the changes.

Comment: Full Disk Access did it! Thanks. I don't even need to be root. Still seems odd that root doesn't get you past that.

Comment: In case someone ends up here with the same problem, in addition to copying over the contents of that directory, I also had to "Reopen All Windows from Last Session" under "History" in Safari.

Comment: @MarkAdler It might seem odd, if you're looking at it from the perspective of the security model of "olden day Un*x". In modern systems it is common to restrict what the root user is able to do. For example, if you're running Linux, SELinux restricts even the root from doing certain things.

Comment: In fact you correctly detected the fact that I'm really old. I am from those days.

Comment: @MarkAdler Given that it was only ~18 years ago that this change happened, most of us are from those days :-)